# How to override inherited getter from java class in a kotlin companion object

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-companion

First of all, `Manager` (a Kotlin class) inherits from `JavaPlugin` (which is a Java class).
This JavaPlugin class contains a getter method `getPlugin(Class<T>)`.

Manager class:

```kotlin
class Manager : JavaPlugin() {

    companion object {
        [more code...]
        lateinit var plugin: Manager
            private set
    }

    [more code...]

}
```

Now back in any other Java class (my project is mixed between the two languages) I want to call `Manager.getPlugin()`, but in Java there is still only the method from the `JavaPlugin` class, which was inherited.
In Kotlin files, I am able to retrieve plugin variable, but in Java files, I could not figure out how this possible.

I know that I could use `Manager.Companion.getPlugin()` now, but **I do not want to change my old Java code** (which contains the old static `Manager.getPlugin()` call).

Am I just wrong here with the companion object and should use something different in order to emulate my old static variable with a static getter? (I read that you could place the variables outside of the class, but I did not get how to access these variables then under the name `Manager` (it only worked with `ManagerKt`).)

> I hope someone has a better title for this question and edits it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotate your method [`@JvmStatic`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#static-methods).